# Unable to connect to mysql flexible server from deployed node azure function using sequelize and Serverless Framework

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, azure-functions, sequelize.js

As the title says, I have a series of azure functions (function app) which call on a database (mysql) also deployed on azure using sequelize and all of them are in the same resource group (deployed to us-east-2).

When I run the api locally everything works, I am able to make calls to the api and it is able to communicate to the DB. I can deploy everything just fine using Serverless Framework but when I try to make a call to one of the deployed endpoints I get the following 500 error returned:

{
"name": "SequelizeConnectionError",
"parent": {
"errno": "EACCES",
"code": "EACCES",
"syscall": "connect",
"address": "127.0.0.1",
"port": 3306,
"fatal": true
},
"original": {
"errno": "EACCES",
"code": "EACCES",
"syscall": "connect",
"address": "127.0.0.1",
"port": 3306,
"fatal": true
}
}

Could this connection error be due to my credentials not being deployed with sequelize? If so, how do I deploy them? I have them stored as environment variables in a local.settings.json file. I checked the firewall and since this is a Proof of Concept with dummy data I am just letting everything in so it can't be that.

Here is my sequelize connection:

```js
const {
    Sequelize,
} = require("sequelize");

const DATABASE_HOST = process.env["DATABASE_HOST"];
const DATABASE_CATALOG = process.env["DATABASE_CATALOG"];
const DATABASE_PORT = process.env["DATABASE_PORT"];
const DATABASE_USER = process.env["DATABASE_USER"];
const DATABASE_PASSWORD = process.env["DATABASE_PASSWORD"];

const sequelize = new Sequelize(DATABASE_CATALOG, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD, {
    host: DATABASE_HOST,
    port: DATABASE_PORT,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    ssl: true,
    "dialectOptions": {
        "ssl": {
            "require": true
        }
    },
    pool: {
    max: 20,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 120000,
    idle: 10000
  }
});


module.exports = sequelize;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, its a side project and I have been staring at this for way too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the required configuration setting physically inside the azure portal.

```
function app >> configuration >> application setting
```

[image]
Click on new application settings

[image]

After adding the required setting like your credentials, you have to restart the function.

Now you can call this setting in you app in a similar way like this :-

```
const port = process.env.PORT ;
```